# Praying in a public place (theme park)

Tags: salat

Asalaamu alaikum brothers and sisters,
I have a question, well I need advice.
Tomorrow I am going Blackpool pleasure beach which is a funfair. I had planned to pray zuhr there however my aunty and my mum think it's best if I don't. They think it would be better to pray zuhr when I come home which will be about 8pm-ish. I told them I'm going to pray in an area in the theme park. Instead of saying okay, they basically took the piss out of me. Well my aunty did, not my mum. My aunty said people will think odd of me and that the area I'm going to pray in, may be dirty and not clean. As we are going on a Saturday, the theme park will be busy. Also, I won't be able to pray in the car park because once you go out, you can't come back in AND we are all going by train.
Overall, they advise me to pray when I get home. But how do I do that? I feel really crappy and I know I will feel guilty tomorrow if I miss zuhr prayer tomorrow. Help? And my sister said to pray zuhr with asr once I get home because my aunty thinks backward and isn't going to budge on the idea.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure (even on a Saturday) you can find a clean place to pray. If not, you can go into the administrative office and ask them for permission to pray in there.

Praying is allowed anywhere, as long as the place is clean. It is best to pray on time (you can combine Zuhur and Asr for feasibility purposes).

Answer (score -1):

Assalam o Alykum Brother,
Don't worry, you can pray at my place (Tudor Rose Original) guest house... its just next to Pleasure Beach.
5 Withnell Road
FY4 1HF
South Shore.

Comment: While it's encouraging to see such generosity, the original post is dated from over a year ago.